# How do I build 32-bit executables on x86_64 Fedora?

Tags: fedora, cpu-architecture

I am trying to run 32bit executables on 64bit Fedora 21.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf ("Hello C\n");

    return 1;
}


cc -m32 hello.c   -o helloi686
```

Executable returns bad system call, or not a dynamic executable.

Installed packages

```
 glibc                                      i686                       2.20-8.fc21                                  @updates                                                   15 M
 glibc-devel                                i686                       2.20-8.fc21                                  @updates                                                  1.0 M
 libX11                                     i686                       1.6.2-2.fc21                                 @fedora                                                   1.3 M
 libXau                                     i686                       1.0.8-4.fc21                                 @fedora                                                    49 k
 libXext                                    i686                       1.3.3-2.fc21                                 @fedora                                                    87 k
 libXrandr                                  i686                       1.4.2-2.fc21                                 @fedora                                                    46 k
 libXrender                                 i686                       0.9.8-4.fc21                                 @fedora                                                    45 k
 libgcc                                     i686                       4.9.2-6.fc21                                 @updates                                                  202 k
 libstdc++                                  i686                       4.9.2-6.fc21                                 @updates                                                  1.0 M
 libxcb                                     i686                       1.11-3.fc21                                  @updates                                                  875 k
 ncurses-libs                               i686                       5.9-16.20140323.fc21                         @fedora                                                   932 k
 nss-softokn-freebl                         i686                       3.18.0-1.fc21                                @updates                                                  432 k
 zlib                                       i686                       1.2.8-7.fc21                                 @fedora                                                   187 k
```

In command line:

```
[root@machine platform-tools]# ldconfig -v | grep ld-linux
        ld-linux.so.2 -> ld-2.20.so
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> ld-2.20.so

[root@machine platform-tools]# ls -l /lib/ld-2.20.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 159020 feb 27 13:02 /lib/ld-2.20.so
```

What packages should solve this problem?

Comment: What does `ldd helloi686` say?

Comment: $ldd helloi686 "not a dynamic executable"

Comment: Any useful messages from `cc -Wall -m32 hello.c  -o helloi686`, or `file helloi686`?

Comment: file helloi686: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=4e2190e93b0b50901a5097701f89b95b5e33129f, not stripped

Comment: How about `objdump -p helloi686 | grep NEEDED` output?

Comment: Does `/lib/ld-2.20.so helloi686` work?

Comment: NEEDED               libc.so.6
/lib/ld-2.20.so helloi686 "Bad system call" /lib/ld-2.20.so "Bad system call"

Comment: Does `strace helloi686` and/or `strace /lib/ld-2.20.so helloi686` show the exact "Bad system call"?

Comment: Both, +++ killed by SIGSYS +++

Comment: On what/which system call(s) did the SIGSYS occur?  If you install the static libraries and compile with the `-static` flag, does helloi686 execute properly then?

Comment: # cc -Wall -m32 -static -g hello.c -o helloi686 ; ./helloi686 : "Bad system call"

Comment: strace stops after execve("./helloi686",...)

Comment: And does a `-static` compile work?

Answer (score 0):

Could be systemd config file system.conf has enabled SystemCallArchitectures with other arch.

Adjust/remove it. dracut -f, and reboot.